# Type initializer exception "the RPC server is unavailable"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

We have an unusual error in one of our environments. The application is .Net 3.5, and at a particular point this error comes back

> The type initializer for 'Documents.Document' threw an
>   exception. The RPC server is unavailable.

The code that is causing this issue is this line

```
Document.ToString(DocumentFileContentsType.BinBase64)
```

and the method that it calls that throws the exception is:

```
public static string ToString(DocumentFileContentsType fileContentsType)
    {
        string fileContentsTypeText = null;

        switch (fileContentsType)
        {
            case DocumentFileContentsType.BinBase64:
                fileContentsTypeText = "BIN.BASE64";
                break;
            case DocumentFileContentsType.BinHex:
                fileContentsTypeText = "BIN.HEX";
                break;
            case DocumentFileContentsType.Gemini:
                fileContentsTypeText = "GEMINI";
                break;
            case DocumentFileContentsType.DmsGemini:
                fileContentsTypeText = "GEMINI.BIN.BASE64";
                break;
            case DocumentFileContentsType.Cmis:
                fileContentsTypeText = "CMIS";
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid FILECONTENTS_TYPE: " + fileContentsType.ToString() + ".", "fileContentsType");
        }

        return fileContentsTypeText;
    }
```

So there is no kind of network communication or inter process call or anything happening that I can see.

Any ideas?

Comment: The static constructor of `Documents.Document` fails because it cannot load / call a dependency (that is likely a COM component, possibly an out-of-proc server). Cross-process calls are made through a local variant of RPC, that's why you're getting that error message. You can try using ILSpy to see what the static constructor is doing.

Comment: Ah yes, that sounds reasonable. There are a ton of dependencies, so I will have to investigate further

Comment: Do you have Word as a dependency?

Comment: No, not word, but we do have a component that takes rtf documents and turns them into pdf that may be the culprit